# can I get a explanation about robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I just want to know whether you need robots.txt in your website for the crawler to index the pages. Or it is just to disallow any content that you dont want to index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need robots.txt for the crawler to index. It's the opposite, it is used to ban certain robots for some parts of the site.

All you need to know is here: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Answer (score 0):

I disagree, a `robots.txt` can (and should) be used when one or multiple maps are used. Although they are not mandatory, it is highly recommended to use them to facilitate indexing.